# I got the error JoinRandomRoom failed. And I don't understand what the problem is because everything worked yesterday

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon

**I'm Connected To Master, the server is created and the game is the same version.**
**Here is my error** "JoinRandomRoom failed. Client is on MasterServer (must be Master Server for matchmaking) but not ready for operations (State: Joining). Wait for callback: OnJoinedLobby or OnConnectedToMaster.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:JoinRandomRoom (ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable,byte,Photon.Realtime.MatchmakingMode,Photon.Realtime.TypedLobby,string,string[]) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetwork.cs:1663)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:JoinRandomRoom () (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetwork.cs:1597)
join:JoinRoom () (at Assets/Scripts/join.cs:27)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.ugui@1.0.0/Runtime/EventSystem/EventSystem.cs:385)"

**here is my code:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class join : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
     public Text LogText;
private void Start()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.NickName = "Player" + Random.Range(1000, 9999);
        Log("Player`s name is set to" + PhotonNetwork.NickName);
        //try to connect
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }
    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
       Log("conected to master");
    }
    public void CreateRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(null, new Photon.Realtime.RoomOptions());
    }
    public void JoinRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
    }
    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("SampleScene");
    }
    private void Log(string message)
    {
        Debug.Log(message);
        LogText.text  += "\n";
        LogText.text  += message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are calling JoinRandomRoom more than once. When this error gets logged, the client logs "State: Joining", so one join operation was already called.